# compare an object with a json schema and fill it with the schema default values if they are not set

Tags: json, ruby, validation, jsonschema

I'm using [Ruby JSON Schema Validator](https://github.com/ruby-json-schema/json-schema) to validate some of my input data, which is quite nice.

But I would like to update my input data so that it takes the default values of the schema if its values are not set.

```
  input = {'url' => 'http://www.google.com'}

  schema = {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "url": {
        "type": "string",
      },
      "infos":{
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "content_type": {
            "type": "string",
            "default": "html",
          },
        }
      }
    }
  }

  #make some magic here to update my input with the schema

  output = {
      'url' => 'http://www.google.com',
      'infos' => {'content_type'=>'html'}
  }
```

How could I achieve this, knowing that the structure of the input is not the same as the one of the schema ?

There is an *:insert_defaults* option with the [Ruby JSON Schema Validator](https://github.com/ruby-json-schema/json-schema), but I don't see a way to retrieve the filled object.
Seems that the code related to that is [here](https://github.com/ruby-json-schema/json-schema/blob/2f95d53d62428d603601a1346d6e12a70e7a505d/lib/json-schema/attributes/properties.rb#L14).

I've also searched Google, made some attempts with *deep_merge()*, but since the structures to compare are not identical, I don't know how to handle this.

Comment: _Is this possible?_ Yes, it is. Is there anything you've have tried?

Comment: I think that's only for "during the validation process". You'll either need to find another library or roll your own solution for this.

Comment: Yes, I've seen that. But could be a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with :

```
def defaultsFromSchema(node,nodekeys=[],datas={})
  return unless node.is_a?(Hash)

  if node.has_key?('default')
    value = node['default']
    #create hash and set deep keys
    return nodekeys.reverse.inject(value) { |a, n| { n => a } }

  else
    node.each do |k, v|
      keys = nodekeys.clone
      if k != 'properties'
        keys.push(k)
      end

      append = defaultsFromSchema(v,keys,datas)
      if append
        datas = datas.deep_merge(append)
      end

    end
  end

  datas

end
```